# Set the column value of a found cell to a name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set values for variables to be used later on in my code based on the column value of a found cell.
Thanks to some existing subject, I was able to find the cell, but I am unable to set its column value to a name.

Here is my code:

```
Dim rFind As Range


With Range("A1:DD1")
Set rFind = .Find(What:="FIND", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

MsgBox rFind.Column


End With

End Sub
```

The MsgBox returns the correct column number but my attempts at getting it set to a name has failed.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

My goal is to create an automatic table with data extracted from another table. I want to use the column number to extract data for each row of my table from the correct column. I currently use a system where I "hardcode" my names for the current column number (e.g.: Publi Const example As Integer = 5). However this is not a flexible solution if my data table were to change (new or removed columns). Finding the column to then set it would solve the issue.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "set to a name" and show what you have tried please? Do you mean naming the whole column?

Comment: Yes, let me explain: My goal is to create an automatic table with data extracted from another table. I want to use the column number to extract data for each row of my table from the correct column. I currently use a system where I "hardcode" my names for the current column number (e.g.: Publi Const example As Integer = 5). However this is not a flexible solution if my data table were to change (new or removed columns). Finding the column to then set it would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this, to name the whole column?

```
rFind.EntireColumn.Name = "Fred"
```

Fuller code

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range

With Range("A1:DD1")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="FIND", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        rFind.EntireColumn.Name = "Fred"
    Else
        msgbox "Not found"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, this reuslts in a 424 error: object required.

Comment: On that line? Btw you should always check first that Find returns something before using the result.

Comment: Correcting with the full code you provided results in no error message, so that's already a good step! However "Fred" has an <out of context> value

Comment: What is an "out of context" value?

Comment: I think that I understand. Fred is initially correctly given the value of the column number, however once the macro is completed, this data is erased and my watch on Fred results in an out of context value. My guess is that I should make Fred a public Constant one way or another.

Comment: I don't understand what else you are doing. If you run that code above and Find returns something you will have a named range called "Fred", and that is not erased when the code ends.